# How to execute a J Query script only after the previous one has been executed?

Tags: jquery

I want to change an image after the user scrolls past it, so that when they scroll back up there is a new image. I then want to revert the image back to the original after the user scrolls past the changed image, so that when they scroll back up the old image is there. I want this to be repeat indefinitely.

I am trying to program a simple webpage such that a div with an image (defined by css) changes to a different image after the user has scrolled past, and then reverts back to the original image when the user has again scrolled past the changed image. I am intending for this to repeat every time the user scrolls up the page to see the original image and then back down.

the fiddle script is here: https://jsfiddle.net/flixc3/hgjy86zm/9/#&togetherjs=wmliLo5BIP

I can get the image to change, but not to revert.

```js
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // how many pixels you've scrolled
        var os = $('#div1').offset().top; // pixels to the top of div1
        var ht = $('#div1').height(); // height of div1 in pixels
        // if you've scrolled further than the top of div1 plus it's height
        // change the color. either by adding a class or setting a css property
        if(scroll > os + ht){
            $('#div1').removeClass('english').addClass('japanese');
        }
    });
});
  
   $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll2 = $(window).scrollTop(); // how many pixels you've scrolled
        var os2 = $('#div1').offset().top; // pixels to the top of div1
        var ht2 = $('#div1').height(); // height of div1 in pixels
        // if you've scrolled further than the top of div1 plus it's height
        // change the color. either by adding a class or setting a css property
        if(scroll2 > os2 + ht2){
            $('#div1').removeClass('japanese').addClass('english');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use a single function, and have it set a variable indicating which way it should go each time.

Answer (score 0):

You called the same scroll function twice but still, you check the same thing. Condition is the same.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll2 = $(window).scrollTop(); // how many pixels you've scrolled
        var os2 = $('#div1').offset().top; // pixels to the top of div1         
        var ht2 = $('#div1').height(); // height of div1 in pixels
        // if you've scrolled further than the top of div1 plus it's height
        // change the color. either by adding a class or setting a css property
        if(scroll2 > os2 + ht2){
            $('#div1').removeClass('english').addClass('japanese');
        }else{
            $('#div1').removeClass('japanese').addClass('english');
        }
    });
});
```

Add the code you used for revert the image inside else.

Comment: Thank you for the help -I believe that this function triggers both at the same time causing the else clause to null the if.